# THREE.CanvasRender glitch on android >4.1 WebView

Tags: canvas, webview, three.js, android-webview, android-canvas

I am having trouble with `THREE.CanvasRender` in Android WebView.

My app is working on HTML5 WebView. I do not understand why, in some cases, it doesn't work.  But it works in Android 2.3.3 .. 2.3.7.

I need CanvasRender because most Android devices don't support WebGL in Android WebView.

**Android 2.3.7:** Why does it work?

[image: Android 2.3.7 Screen]

**Android 4.2.2:**

[image: Android 4.2.2 Screen]

In WebGLrender it works great. Here is the code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Crone/78uLtwzy/1

I think I have trouble with parameters.
Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that Android WebView doesn't support WebGL?

Comment: mrdoob, Hi. I'm sure, Android 2.3.7 works fine without webgl. Android 4.1+ doesn't support webgl and render with some glitches. I have tested app on android tablet android v5+(canvas) has glitches too. I have tested it in three.js revision 49, mb new version could solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like WebView smooth filters the fills by default. Fortunately there should be a property to control that.

Try doing this:

```
renderer.getContext().imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

If it doesn't work, try with:

```
renderer.getContext().webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

More info: http://vaughnroyko.com/state-of-nearest-neighbor-interpolation-in-canvas/

Comment: if i using renderer.getContext().imageSmoothingEnabled = false; or webkit, render is broken on the screen is blank. I read a lot about it, many people say that i need to call the function for each frame rendering imageSmoothingEnabled. Some say that i need a large-scale drawing. I can not figure it out. Now i testing only in firefox and IE.

Comment: i used this in render function no result. var ctx = renderer.getContext(); ctx.ImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                                                     i also used in render this                                                                           var b_canvas = document.getElementById("circle");
  var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d");
  b_context.ImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
   where 'circle' id my main canvas. I dont undestand where make mistake i rly need help.

Comment: Ok i resolved this problem i used crosswalk view(chromium 36) and enable web gl.